# Real size of Android dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

How can I know the real size of some custom dialog box with specified "fill_parent" measures?

Explanation:

I have an XML with a custom dialog box. The W/H sizes are "fill_parent".
Android shows some cute dialog box much lesser than X/Y of screen.
I'd like to know the exact size of this dialog after it was shown.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view has two pairs of Size values.

One pair is `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`, this value describes how big specific widget wants to be.

Second pair is `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, called drawable Width and drawable Height, this values describe Size of the widget after drawing.

Keep in mind padding as well.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Not working. I'm receiving "0" in both due to "-1" specified in the "LayoutParams".

Comment: Also how can I obtain the main View of Dialog? Is it Decor? Thanks.

Comment: @OGP you probably already figured this out, but they equal 0 until the view is measured (onMeasure()) is called.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm for more than a year is off Android development. I really don't remember why I asked the Q first hand. Sorry.